# Can FindInMap return a list?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I'm using CloudFormation to deploy an ELB to a pre-existing VPC which has pre-existing Subnets. I've listed the subnets in a Mappings section of the template and select the mapping based on the Environment parameter. This works fine if the Mapping is for a single value, but I want the Mapping to return a list as I want the ELB to be multi-AZ.
I've tried various combinations of the example below, but I always get the same error `Value of property Subnets must be of type List of String`.
Is there a way that FindInMap can return a list of values?

Example ELB Config

```
"ElasticLoadBalancerAPI": {
            "Properties": {
                "ConnectionDrainingPolicy": {
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "Timeout": 30
                },
                "ConnectionSettings": {
                    "IdleTimeout": 60
                },
                "CrossZone": "false",
                "Subnets" : [
                    {
                        "Fn::FindInMap": [
                            "AWSEnv2PublicSubnets",
                            {
                                "Ref": "Env"
                            },
                            "subList"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup" }],
etc...
```

Example Parameters

```
"Parameters": {
  "Env": {
            "Description": "Environment",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "DEV",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "DEV",
                "TEST"
            ]
        }
}
```

Example Mappings

```
"Mappings": {
  "AWSEnv2PublicSubnets": {
            "DEV": {
                "subList": ["subnet-1111","subnet-2222","subnet-3333"]
            },
            "TEST": {
                "subList": ["subnet-4444"]
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the [Split](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html) function works:

#### JSON

```
"Mappings": {
   "AWSEnv2PublicSubnets": {
        "DEV": {
            "subList": "subnet-1111,subnet-2222,subnet-3333"
        }
    }
}
```

then:

```
"Subnets" : { 
  "Fn::Split" : [
    ",", 
    { "Fn::FindInMap": [
      "AWSEnv2PublicSubnets",
      { "Ref": "Env" },
      "subList"
    ] }
  ]
}
```

#### YAML

```
Mappings: 
  AWSEnv2PublicSubnets:
    DEV:
      subList: subnet-1111,subnet-2222,subnet-3333
```

then:

```
Subnets: !Split [",", !FindInMap [ AWSEnv2PublicSubnets, !Ref Env, subList] ]
```

I used a comma (`,`) as my separator character, but you can use anything you want so long as it's not also used as a part of the value.

Comment: I did manage to get it working with an answer almost identical. I had the FindInMap inside a set of braces. But I'll mark yours as the correct answer.
`"Mappings" : {
    "AWSEnv2PublicSubnets": {
      "DEV": { "subList" : "subnet-1111,subnet-2222,subnet-3333" },
      "TEST": { "subList" : "subnet-4444,subnet-5555" }
    }
  }`

Then the Subnet setting was like 
`"Subnets" : { "Fn::Split" : [ ",", { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSEnv2PublicSubnets", { "Ref" : "Env" }, "subList" ]} ] }`

Comment: @user3188040 Ah sorry, I think I just messed up the JSON syntax. I only use YAML for CF templates, so just provided a JSON answer since you asked in JSON.

Answer (score 11):

I think Mappings value supports `List` type (at least as of now).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html

> The Mappings section consists of the key name Mappings. The keys in mappings must be literal strings. The values can be `String` or `List` types.

Here is the example written in YAML.

```
Parameters:
  Env:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [dev, qa, prod]

Mappings:
  Environment:
    dev:
      Groups:
        - Developer
        - QA
    qa:
      Groups:
        - Developer
        - QA
    prod:
      Groups:
        - Operations

Resources:
  Policy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: iam-manage-role
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - iam:*Role*
            Resource: "*"
      Groups: !FindInMap [Environment, !Ref Env, Groups]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I got the following error:

`Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; ....`

Comment: `Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument` - most likely you put indentation wrong somewhere in you yaml?